# Using "as" instead of "that" (I don't know as this is valid)

Tags: syntactic-analysis, dialects, relative-determiners

When answering the ELL question [“I can't say **as** ever I was lost” quoted Daniel Boone,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170552/i-cant-say-as-ever-i-was-lost-quoted-daniel-boone/170576#170576) I said that having ***as*** instead of ***that*** in the cited context was a "dialectal, folksy" usage. Then I came up with these two examples...

> 1: *Wealthy man **that** he is, John cannot buy happiness.*
>    2: *Wealthy **as** he is, John cannot buy happiness.*

...which both seem syntactically valid to my ear. I don't think I could say the same if the two highlighted words were swapped, but I'm less sure about that.

Can anyone explain what's going on here? And either support or refute my perception that #1 and #2 above are valid as presented, but not if the usages were reversed?

Comment: It's a local speech variant. Probably only used by a small segment of some speech groups. Also, Daniel Boone's dialect of English hasn't been spoken since about 1900.

Comment: What is heard is: I can't say as I have ever lost. I don't see highlighted words on my screen. How is your posted Daniel Boone sentence related to 1) and 2)?

Comment: @Lambie - The highlighted words are "that" and "as."   Does your interface allow you to click on "edit"?  That would show you underscore characters or asterisks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples become less liable to questions of interchangeability when they are both properly parsed as [absolute constructions](https://www.thoughtco.com/absolute-phrase-grammar-1689049) with ellipsis. When an absolute in sentence-initial position merely describes a state, such as being wealthy or a wealthy man, the participle is often omitted:

> 19.10.2017.  [*The astute politician that he is*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-21587054), Mr Odinga has been using allegory and riddles to tell his supporters how the electoral commission denied him of victory. — “Raila Odinga - the man Kenyans either love or loathe,” BBC News.

In other contexts, the participle is usually expressed:

> In a skewed way, Kathy's actions had forced Cory to make a better life for himself, but [*being the man he was*](https://books.google.de/books?id=V7MYBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&dq=%22being+the+man+he%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-ydbDr_7bAhVlKpoKHT1LAlQQ6AEIRDAF), he would have done it anyway. — Gail Sattler, *Dating the Best Man*, 2015, 171.

and especially when the participle is not used absolutely:

> Robbed of control by virtue of [*being a woman and the particular woman that she is*](https://books.google.de/books?id=vuZyAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA210&lpg=PA210&dq=%22woman+that+she+is%22&source=bl&ots=OTbIb8inYE&sig=qePHQvorkmd9enTd2_wxyEefw10&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRvOOxp_7bAhWpQZoKHU-QCDQQ6AEwEnoECAgQAQ), the anorexic, like the self-mutilating woman, has seized control over the one area that women are encouraged to control, and she is holding on to it desperately.— Bonnie Burstow, *Radical Feminist Therapy: Working in the Context of Violence*, 1992.

Your second example omits both the initial participle and the first conjunction in an adjectival *as (adj.) as* construction, which may or may not be expressed:

> [*As intelligent as he is*](https://books.google.de/books?id=4aRciaCXbTAC&pg=PA14&dq=%22intelligent+as+he+is%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjovbbEqf7bAhWLaFAKHdKDCHUQ6AEIJDAA), he misjudges the evil of the others, believing they can be spoken with rationally and never realizes the seriousness of the situation and the potential for a deathly response. — Harold Bloom, *William Golding's Lord of the Flies*, Bloom’s Guides, 2004, 14.

Though still current after *say*, the non-standard, highly colloquial *as* introducing a relative clause in the Daniel Boone citation was far more frequent and occurred in more contexts in earlier centuries than today:

> ‘Why, I [*can’t say as*](https://books.google.de/books?id=JXxiDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=%22can%27t+say+as+I%22&source=bl&ots=nzdBeOhfOy&sig=DUnH4DaDxeU4Jn7DvTNTe6KGOSY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9j5GbuP7bAhUhQZoKHaB5Ato4ChDoATACegQIBBAB) I know any real harm of her,’ said her mother, ‘unless it’s *as* she’s a Catholic.’
>   ‘Totty Nancarrow a Catholic!’ exclaimed Ackroyd. ’Why, I never knew that.’
>   ‘Her mother was Irish, you see, an’ I don’t suppose *as* her father thought much about religion. I dessay there’s some good people Catholics, but I can’t say *as* I take much to them I know.’ — George Gissing, *Thyrza*, 1887.
>
> Dealing with the blues, but [*can’t say as*](http://www.joemonks.com/dealing-with-the-blues-but-cant-say-as-im-suffering/) I’m suffering. [*Joseph M. Monks*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_M._Monks), filmmaker, born Queens NYC, Blog post, 8 Feb. 2017.

Comment: |I can't say as I have ever| is still common today. The ever is postpositioned today.

Comment: Yes, that word order seems to have disappeared in the 1920's, but that wasn't the point of the question. https://elephind.com/?a=q&results=1&deq=&e=------191-en-10--1--txt-txINtxCO-%22say+as+ever+I%22---------

Comment: This one does it for me. I now see that my two examples are both different to the original Boone quote *and* to each other, which explains why I can't just swap ***as*** and ***that*** in mine the way we could with Boone's. Until you pointed it out, I hadn't explicitly recognised that my *[the] wealthy man that he is* is effectively a "noun phrase" referencing the same real-world referent as immediately-following *John* (similar to, say, ***Poor John, he** can't buy happiness*, I think), whereas *wealthy as he is* is an adjectival element, not a noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Someone named se16teddy [posted](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cant-say-as-i-have.2374223/) about this at forum.wordreference.com:

> The OED has this usage as No. 26 of as, adverb and conjunction.
>
> 26. Introducing a noun clause, after say, know, think, etc.; = that conjunction 1a.
>
> It marks this usage: Now England regional (southern) and U.S.
> regional.
>
> The OED's examples include the following:
>
> 1484 Caxton tr. G. de la Tour-Landry *Bk. Knight of Tower* (1971)
> lxiiii. 94, I saye not as ye shalle be pryuely and allone one by
> other.
>
> 1856 H. B. Stowe *Dred* xi. 100, I don't know as you'll like the
> appearance of our place.
>
> 1997 F. Chappell *Farewell I'm bound to leave*
> *You* 11, I don't know as I believe that talk.

It sounds quaint and folksy to my ear but not uncontemporary (is there a better word for that?).

Comment: +1 for useful info re use of ***as*** instead of ***that*** by Boone, but I have to go with @KarlG for the breakdown of why my examples are different (both to the Boone example and to each other).

Answer (score 0):

Using either "that" or "as" there is valid.  HOWEVER, in your second example, you omit the word "man" after "as," which materially changes it from the first example.

In order to have the second example parallel the first example, you must include the word "man" beforehand like you do in the first.  While the second example is grammatical, by omitting "man," you change its meaning and structure to something different than the first example's.  That's because by eliminating the noun "man" after the adjective "wealthy," you are changing what is a left dislocation into an absolute phrase.

Examples:

- "I can't say as I'm surprised."

[Source 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=NCFIPuK2sKYC&pg=PT57&lpg=PT57&dq=%22I%20can't%20say%20as%20I'm%20surprised%22&source=bl&ots=5mmYqV9y71&sig=mJ2YZ1Kzsd_azo2xlVLtB59Pksc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvkrjis__bAhUs9YMKHbaXA44Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22I%20can't%20say%20as%20I'm%20surprised%22&f=false)
[Source 2](http://2https://books.google.com/books?id=OoiGBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT113&lpg=PT113&dq=%22I%20can't%20say%20as%20I'm%20surprised%22&source=bl&ots=1rbiwmcs7U&sig=4wS-o0yeyjbZMM7njEhNByoRGOg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvkrjis__bAhUs9YMKHbaXA44Q6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=%22I%20can't%20say%20as%20I'm%20surprised%22&f=false)
[Source 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=VOsBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA237&lpg=PA237&dq=%22I%20can't%20say%20as%20I'm%20surprised%22&source=bl&ots=kJSM4xHXVf&sig=ZY6ZQ-ogHDzrKb8RlrLSAhhih_U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvkrjis__bAhUs9YMKHbaXA44Q6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22I%20can't%20say%20as%20I'm%20surprised%22&f=false)

- "I can't say that I'm surprised."

[Source 4](https://books.google.com/books?id=REDQAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=%22I%20can't%20say%20that%20I'm%20surprised%22&source=bl&ots=L0SMKuJV_5&sig=hOLcGErrEPJryXms5V61XkQGybw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOirWHtP_bAhXC6oMKHdI_AkcQ6AEIXzAL#v=onepage&q=%22I%20can't%20say%20that%20I'm%20surprised%22&f=false)
[Source 5](https://books.google.com/books?id=-_UNV7y3nJIC&pg=PA364&dq=%22can't%20say%20that%20I'm%20surprised%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF_uy_tP_bAhVs64MKHedkBsAQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22can't%20say%20that%20I'm%20surprised%22&f=false) 
[Source 6](https://books.google.com/books?id=oV5noACeIAkC&pg=PA129&dq=%22can't%20say%20that%20I'm%20surprised%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF_uy_tP_bAhVs64MKHedkBsAQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22can't%20say%20that%20I'm%20surprised%22&f=false)

Both of the above examples mean the exact same thing.

Do you see that "I can't say as ever I was lost" and "I can't say that ever I was lost" mean the same thing, but "I can't say as ever was lost" doesn't mean the same thing and is wrong?  Well, that's what you do when you eliminate the word "man" in your second example.  It's just that, unlike in your Daniel Boone quote, you've provided a construction where omitting the noun after "as," while changing the meaning and the construction, doesn't create a syntactical error like it does in the Daniel Boone quote.