# I don't know as I blame you much

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean?
Does it mean I don't blame you?
"I don't know" means "I'm not sure"?
What does "as" mean in this sentence?

I'm sorry for the confusion.

It is from "Stuart Little - E. B. White".
The text is as follows：

"Ah," said Stuart, "summers are wonderful, aren't they, Katharine?"

"Yes, and last summer was the most wonderful summer I have ever had in all my life."

"I can imagine," replied Stuart. "You're sure you wouldn't want to sell that little pillow?"

Katharine shook her head.

"**Don't know as I blame you**," replied Stuart, quietly. "Summertime is important. It's like a shaft of sunlight."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "as" instead of "that" (I don't know as this is valid)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452787/using-as-instead-of-that-i-dont-know-as-this-is-valid)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! When you quote text, it helps us enormously if you say where it comes from and who write it. Also, if possible, please give us a link to the original.

Comment: And give us the actual sentence containing the text, not just a few words.

Comment: The direct meaning is *I don't blame you for that*, and it's common in conversation. Similarly, *I can't say jumping off the cliff is best*. Such understatement shows up in upper registers, too, in *We are not amused*, meaning angry.